# Why animated drawable doesn't appear

Tags: android, xml, animation, layout, drawable

I want to create animated drawable from 14 png images.
I added the 14 images to all drawable- folders, and created a animated-list like below, but nothing appear, what is the problem ?

circle.xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f6" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f7" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f8" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f9" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f10" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f11" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f12" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f13" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f14" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
package pit.opensource.animation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircleAnimationActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btnStart;
    ImageView imgCircle;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        imgCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCircle);
        imgCircle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);

        AnimationDrawable ani = (AnimationDrawable) imgCircle.getBackground();
        ani.start();
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //  ani.start();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: where do you use animated-list.xml ?

Comment: @Snicolas it is for circle.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background should be animation, you should put circle.xml to res/anim, and change

```
imgCircle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
```

to

```
imgCircle.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.circle);
```

Try following code to start the animation

```
   imgCircle.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AnimationDrawable ani = (AnimationDrawable) imgCircle.getBackground();
            ani.start();
        }
    });
```

or implement move the animation start to onWindowFocusChanged

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean flag) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(flag);
    AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) imgCircle.getBackground();
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: @Bader The cycle.xml should be in res/anim folder, and you need to set the background with imgCircle.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.circle)

Comment: How said that ? Look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Comment: @Bader I didn't look at the doc before.. Both of them works, but I prefer to put the animation.xml to anim just to make it easy to be found. I built a test project, it works with mine change.

Comment: @Bader As http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html indicated you can start animation in onWindowFocusChanged()

Comment: ,,, in fact I don't know what is the problem , but all attempts lead to the same nothing

Answer (score 0):

There could be third reasons.

First reason is ***OutOfMemoryError***. You need to compress your images.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692328/causing-outofmemoryerror-in-frame-by-frame-animation-in-android)

Second reason is ***android:oneshot*** parameter in your circle.xml. This animation runs for just 14 frames. By setting the android:oneshot attribute of the list to true, it will cycle just once then stop and hold on the last frame. If it is set false then the animation will loop.

Change

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

with

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
```

Third Reason is ***start()*** method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window.

Change your MainActivity.java with this code:

```
package pit.opensource.animation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircleAnimationActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnStart;
    ImageView imgCircle;
    AnimationDrawable ani;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imgCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCircle);
        imgCircle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);

        ani = (AnimationDrawable) imgCircle.getBackground();

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ani.start();

            }

        });

    }

}
```