# How android decodes the Resources

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, size, decode

In the attempt of performing animation with large set of images, I tried with FrameAnimation but I found of outofmemory exception with large set of images, after some exploration for the solution I found one good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692328/causing-outofmemoryerror-in-frame-by-frame-animation-in-android) Pinhassi's solution.
This one helps me to achieve animation but not smoothly because it taking a time to load the images. Then I decided to decode bitmap before starting the animation (giving bitmap instead of resID to ImageView). Through this I got smooth animation. But it is taking a time to decode the bitmap from the resources.

*Is there any better approach to do the same? Any suggestion would be appreciated.*

Details of the image

Total Number of images =30;

Image Dimension =1000x 720;

Size =180kb

Devices on which I am performing

Manufacture: Motorola

Model: MZ601

Android Version: 3.0

To decode Bitmap

```
    Bitmap mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),resID);
    int bitmapSize= mBitmap.getRowBytes()*mBitmap.getHeight())
```

The approximate bitmapSize values is 3000000 (might be it is in bytes) converting it to kilobytes 23437.5kb

Here original png file is 180kb but after decoding it, taking nearly 2MB of data. **Why?**

Is I am doing anything wrong in analyzing the size of bitmap?

If yes, then how to get the size of decode bitmap?

If no, then any one explain why it is taking large space?

Note: I don’t want to scale the bitmap since it is perfect to my device screen dimension which is (1280 x 752).

Thanks

In advance for valuable suggestions and solutions.

Comment: not a full answer but I can clarify a couple of things for you. PNG is a compressed format, to draw to the screen the framework must create an uncompressed version of it, ergo 180k becomes 2mb. Regarding the animation, can't you achieve the same result using the very flexible animation XML http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html ?

Comment: @Budius Thank you for your valuable comment, Since I am dealing with the set of images FrameAnimation would be better for me, But using the FrameAnimation I am facing the out of memory exception.

Comment: Have you considered using `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize`. [here](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/reduce-bitmap-size-using.html). This might help you. Just a suggestion

Comment: @JJPA I have considered insampelSize but it leads to shrink my image dimension which is not valid for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Here original png file is 180kb but after decoding it, taking nearly
>   2MB of data. Why?

Assuming 1 byte per pixel with three color channels(RGB) Byte size =  3X(1000X720)/(1024*1024) = 2.05 MB approx.

There is a limit such processing can reach with plain bitmap loading, that's why Video codec's exist.