# OutOfMemory Error in animation-list android

Tags: android, animation, out-of-memory

I have like 100+ images(frames) in my drawables and each of them are 1-5 kbs size (with resolution 480 x 272). now when I add these images (frames) in animation-list xml and try to run it, I get this OutOfMemory error, I have searched on internet but couldn't find what I am looking for. so anyone can please tell me what should I do to overcome this error

Comment: Use lazyLoader to display large size image

Comment: how can i use lazyloader in xml? i cant use lazyloader as i want these pictures to be in animation-list

Comment: load scaled down images into memory

Comment: see here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: or you can display by creating a handler

Comment: Are you using only One Animation or more than one Animation

Comment: Handler will help you to load all the animation not resolve the problem about OutOfMemory error. If am I right else suggest me @Droid

Comment: Load image sequentially , please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10993879/774305 .

Answer (score 5):

***[Read Article](http://www.a4ios.com/outofmemory-exception-on-animationlarge-image-loading-in-android/)***

Do one thing in the manifest.xml

```
 <application

    android:largeHeap="true">

</application>
```

***`Or`***

make call the Animation in  `runOnUiThread (Runnable action)` or `AsyncTask`

***`Or`***

**Single Image need memory:**

In this case you have 100 images and dimensions are 400*262.

So , 100 * 400*262*4 = ? KB , size occur during the loading time. If the animation is exceeding the limit of Virtual Heap Memory.

Error will occur defiantly.

For this :

Reduce the `dimensions` of Image

Or

use less images for the animation

or

`split into two animation file` after one completion start another one

***EDITED on 16th June 2015***

Try to use `Handler` and call Handler after few millisecond. It will also reduce the memory issue(OOM).