# Android OutOfMemoryError for large images

Tags: java, android

The method throws OutOfMemoryError for large images in size( not by resolution)
i have 12 MP photos, all of them are different in size(1.5MB, 2.5MB, 3.2MB, 4.1MB) etc and the resolution for all of them are same 4000 x 3000 (pixels).

The resizer method works fine for images less than 3MB in size, but for those images that are >3MB it throws OutOfMemoryError i dont know what could fix it, my app is mainly for resizing large images, and this is really getting me nowhere.

The resizer method is:

```
public File resizeBitmap(String imPath, int reqSize) {
    File fl = null;
    try{

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imPath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqSize);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap saveImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imPath, options);

    //save resized image
    String tmpName = "IMG_"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
    fl = fileCache.getRawFile(tmpName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fl);
    saveImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fos);
    saveImg.recycle();


    return fl;
}
catch (Throwable eex){
    eex.printStackTrace();
    if(eex instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(Resizer.this, "Memory ran out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    return null;
 }
}
//Method for calculating insamplesize
public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqSize) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
Log.i("width",""+width);
Log.i("height",""+height);
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqSize || width > reqSize) {

        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqSize);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqSize);
         }


}

return inSampleSize;
```

}

```
//Stacktrace
04-11 09:01:19.832: W/System.err(8832): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-11 09:01:19.953: W/System.err(8832):     at  android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-11 09:01:19.972: W/System.err(8832):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:529)
04-11 09:01:19.993: W/System.err(8832):     at com.scale.app.Resizer.resizeBitmap(Resizer.java:1290)
```

Comment: Increase your `SampleSize`.

Comment: please follow this link :

[OUT OF MEMORY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674906/outofmemory-error-in-animation-list-android/19674967#19674967)

Answer (score 1):

**[Read Article](http://www.a4ios.com/outofmemory-exception-on-animationlarge-image-loading-in-android/)**

Image Size : 4000*3000 in px

When the image load :  4000*3000*4 = ? KB

So,Vitrual Heap Memory of the Android device are : 32 MB, 64 MB , 128 MB ... so on

if you using:

```
<application

    android:largeHeap="true">

</application>
```

This will increase the VHM double (if 32 MB = 2* 32 MB). BUt this will not an good way to do this, effect on OS

You need to decrease the size of the image.

---

Use the below class and pass the path of the image and width , height what you want

> > > > Bitmap bitmap = BitmapSize.getDecodedBitmap(path, 400, 400);

Class::::

```
public class BitmapSize{



public static Bitmap getDecodedBitmap(String path, float target_width, float target_height) {
    Bitmap outBitmap = null;
    try {
        Options decode_options = new Options();
        decode_options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,decode_options);  //This will just fill the output parameters
        int inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(decode_options, target_width, target_height);

        Options outOptions = new Options();
        outOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        outOptions.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        outOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        outOptions.inScaled = false;

        Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,outOptions);
        outBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedBitmap,// (int)target_width, (int)target_height, true);
                (int)((float)decodedBitmap.getWidth() / inSampleSize),
                (int)((float)decodedBitmap.getHeight() / inSampleSize), true);
        System.out.println("Decoded Bitmap: Width "  + outBitmap.getWidth() + " Height = " + outBitmap.getHeight() + " inSampleSize = " + inSampleSize);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return outBitmap;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(Options options, float reqWidth, float reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

}
```

Comment: The app is for resizing purpose of captured images, the photos i have is taken on android phone itself with 12 MP camera, the app resizes the big images to transfer over network, images are never displayed but just resized and saved on new location

Comment: Wait a minute .. I'll paste code for your solution. MAy be you will get help

Comment: wow that did it i just added these two, outOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        outOptions.inScaled = false;

Answer (score 0):

Please try with these Option properties..

```
    BitmapFactory.Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
    opts.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
    opts.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
    opts.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
    opts.inSampleSize = 1;
```

To reduce the quality of image file increase the number of **opts.inSampleSize.** [Click here for more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

And add one more attribute in Manifest.xml in application tag

> android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Can you try opts.inSampleSize = 2; or 3 then check.. pls

Answer (score 0):

Please read http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html how to deal with large Bitmaps.

> The BitmapFactory class provides several decoding methods
>   (decodeByteArray(), decodeFile(), decodeResource(), etc.) for creating
>   a Bitmap from various sources. Choose the most appropriate decode
>   method based on your image data source. These methods attempt to
>   allocate memory for the constructed bitmap and therefore can easily
>   result in an OutOfMemory exception