# AnimationDrawable, are all images loaded in memory

Tags: android

In animation drawable, you can load up an animation list that has multiple frames that would play one after the other. I am just wondering about memory consumption/efficiency here . If  I have 50 or 60 images, does that mean they are all loaded in memory and then rendered one by one, or is it loaded one by one and replacing the older one?

Any idea how this works?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `AnimationDrawable` loads all of the frames into memory at once. You can read more on this here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889854/3026884)