# Android - Playing MP4 in VideoView - no video but audio (Z-Order Doesn't Work)

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to do a simple test playing an MP4 in a VideoView, but I can only hear audio. I've already tried the Z-order trick as suggested in other posts, but it didn't work.

TestLayout.axml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/testLayout"
            android:clipChildren="false">
                <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/testVideo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="170dp"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

TestActivity.cs (button trigger code):

```
    var videoView = (VideoView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.testVideo);
    videoView.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" +Resource.Raw.testVideo));
    videoView.SetMediaController(null);
    videoView.RequestFocus();
    ISurfaceHolder holder = videoView.Holder;
    holder.SetType(SurfaceType.PushBuffers);
    videoView.Start();
    videoView.SetZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    videoView.SetZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Any other suggestions?

MP4 is H.264 encoded using Photoshop and is 320x240.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of factors to review.

- If you are hearing the audio, the video is *playing*, but the video is not being decoded and displayed as expected.
- Is this happening on an emulator or physical device?

  - If emulator, re-test on physical device
- Are you using a **[H.264 Baseline Profile](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)** codec for encoding?

  - Different apps produce different versions of H.264, try encoding via a different app, i.e. `ffmpeg`
- What Android API version?

  - Different versions support different codecs, review the Android docs
- Implement `MediaPlayer.IOnInfoListener` and `MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener` and review the `MediaInfo` and `MediaError` that you might be getting.

Note: I have found that Xamarin's Android Player fails on videos that play fine on Genymotion, same goes for AVD and BlueStacks. In the end, test on physical devices

Create a simple test app for testing your videos and review the [OnError](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) and [OnInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener.html) parameters.

#### `IOnInfoListener/IOnErrorListener` Example:

```
[Activity(Label = "DroidVideo", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity, MediaPlayer.IOnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener
{
    public bool OnError(MediaPlayer mp, [GeneratedEnum] MediaError what, int extra)
    {
        Log.Debug("Media", what.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnInfo(MediaPlayer mp, [GeneratedEnum] MediaInfo what, int extra)
    {
        Log.Info("Media", what.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate { 
            VideoView video = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.myVideo);
            video.SetOnInfoListener(this);
            var videoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + Path.Combine(PackageName, "raw", Resource.Raw.pool.ToString()));
            video.SetVideoURI(videoUri);
            video.Start();
        };
    }
}
```

Layout for the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The example pointed me in the right direction. I can tell videos don't always play correctly on an emulator vs. actual device now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the LinearLayout that is on top of the VideoView invisible when you play the movie and visible again once the video has finished.

Comment: This didn't make any difference, unfortunately.