# load multiple 100 images in imageview android

Tags: android, imageview

I have approximate 100 images and i want to load it in image view. Somehow it crashes and showing me an error. How can i load more images into single image view in sequence. I also want to call some text after particular frames. Like after every 20 frames i want to show text. Any idea how can i do that?

```
      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2419212 byte allocation with 160148 free bytes and 156KB until OOM
                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3747)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:319)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1063)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3736)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:133)
                  at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:408)
                  at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:17228)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatImageView.java:83)
                  at com.example.aakash.giftry.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to free memory of invisible Drawables. some thing like that:

```
if (previousBitMap != null){
    previousBitMap.recycle();
    previousBitMap = null;
}

[...] // load next
```

Check this, how to do it right: [Causing OutOfMemoryError in Frame by Frame Animation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692328/causing-outofmemoryerror-in-frame-by-frame-animation-in-android/10993879#10993879)

Answer (score 0):

```
<application      
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
>
```

Add these lines in manifest

Comment: We need accelerate our hardware performance and increase the heap memory to improve the application memory.

Comment: @dit had you found any alternate solution. pls explain.

Comment: largeHeap just give you more memory, it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Okey, thanks @dit. I already sort out this way. thanks dude :)