# how to recycle images as frame of AnimationDrawable and solve OutOfMemory error in android?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, recycle, animationdrawable

I want to show some exercises in my android app with ViewPager. i use:

- 2 `imageView` ,one of them shows exercises and others shows th counter
- `AnimationDrawable`

  as i eun my app,it has been crashed and shows me `OutOFMemory` error.although android shows all of images automatically, how can i `recycle` images after showing?

  ```
  public class NeckSportFinger extends Fragment {
      private ImageView sportShowing_img, timeShowing_img;
      public static AnimationDrawable animation_sport, animation_time;
      public TextView sportText;

      public NeckSportFinger(){}

      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sport_show, container, false);

          sportShowing_img= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sport_img);
          timeShowing_img= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_img);

          animation_sport = new AnimationDrawable();
          animation_time = new AnimationDrawable();

          animation_sport.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.neck_one), 1500); //1 Sec
          animation_sport.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.neck_one_right), 8500); //1 Sec
          animation_sport.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.neck_one), 1500); //1 Sec
          animation_sport.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.neck_one_left), 8500); //1 Sec




          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t0), 1500); //1 Sec
          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t1), 1500); //1 Sec
          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t2), 1000); //1 Sec
          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t3), 1000); //1 Sec
          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t4), 1000); //1 Sec
          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t5), 1000); //1 Sec
          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t6), 1000); //1 Sec
          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t7), 1000); //1 Sec
          animation_time.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t8), 1000); //1 Sec

          sportShowing_img.setBackgroundDrawable(animation_sport);
          timeShowing_img.setBackgroundDrawable(animation_time);


          sportText= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sport_type);
          sportText.setText(R.string.sport_finger);

          return view;
      }



      public void start() {
          animation_sport.start();
          animation_time.start();
      }

      public void stop() {
          animation_sport.stop();
          animation_time.stop();
      }
  }
  ```

thanks!

Comment: is it crashing while you are displaying the fragment with the animations or later?

Comment: i've 7 exercise group  that showing in ViewPager. as i scroll them, it crash in fourth.